# Flutter doing weird stuff with arrays

Tags: flutter, dart

I really don't know how to describe this, I'm just going to paste here my code and my output.

Code:

```
scan() async {
    Position position =
        await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    CollectionReference coll = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
        DateTime.now().toString() +
            position.latitude.toString() +
            position.latitude.toString());
    // Start scanning
    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
    // Listen to scan results
    var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      // do something with scan results
      var arr = new List();
      for (ScanResult r in results) {
        if (arr.contains(r.hashCode) == false) {
          arr.add(r.hashCode);
          print(arr);
          /*
          coll
              .add({"hash": r.device.hashCode, "rssi": r.rssi})
              .then((value) => print("ok! $value"))
              .catchError((error) => print(error));
        */
        }
      }
    });

    // Stop scanning
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
    testoBottone = "Scansione completata";
    setState(() {});
  }
```

My output:

```
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879]
I/flutter ( 4599): [839208879, 1070525250]
```

The code should check if I already found a Bluetooth device before pushing data to the cloud, but it doesn't work. Do you know how to fix that?

Thank you, and excuse me for the bad question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [project](https://github.com/lupyuen/flutter-blue-sample/blob/master/lib/main.dart). It clearly shows the found Bluetooth device list.

```
 
// Copyright 2017, Paul DeMarco.
// All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_example/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(FlutterBlueApp());
}

class FlutterBlueApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
          }),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothOffScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BluetoothOffScreen({Key key, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.bluetooth_disabled,
              size: 200.0,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            Text(
              'Bluetooth Adapter is ${state != null ? state.toString().substring(15) : 'not available'}.',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .primaryTextTheme
                  .subhead
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Find Devices'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () =>
            FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4)),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
                stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2))
                    .asyncMap((_) => FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map((d) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(d.name),
                            subtitle: Text(d.id.toString()),
                            trailing: StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
                              stream: d.state,
                              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.data ==
                                    BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
                                  return RaisedButton(
                                    child: Text('OPEN'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                DeviceScreen(device: d))),
                                  );
                                }
                                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                              },
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            r.device.connect();
                            return DeviceScreen(device: r.device);
                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning,
        initialData: false,
        builder: (c, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.stop),
              onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            );
          } else {
            return FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance
                    .startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4)));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DeviceScreen({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothDevice device;

  List<int> _getRandomBytes() {
    final math = Random();
    return [
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255)
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    return services
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
            service: s,
            characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
                .map(
                  (c) => CharacteristicTile(
                    characteristic: c,
                    onReadPressed: () => c.read(),
                    onWritePressed: () async {
                      await c.write(_getRandomBytes(), withoutResponse: true);
                      await c.read();
                    },
                    onNotificationPressed: () async {
                      await c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying);
                      await c.read();
                    },
                    descriptorTiles: c.descriptors
                        .map(
                          (d) => DescriptorTile(
                            descriptor: d,
                            onReadPressed: () => d.read(),
                            onWritePressed: () => d.write(_getRandomBytes()),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(device.name),
        actions: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
            stream: device.state,
            initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
            builder: (c, snapshot) {
              VoidCallback onPressed;
              String text;
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
                  onPressed = () => device.disconnect();
                  text = 'DISCONNECT';
                  break;
                case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
                  onPressed = () => device.connect();
                  text = 'CONNECT';
                  break;
                default:
                  onPressed = null;
                  text = snapshot.data.toString().substring(21).toUpperCase();
                  break;
              }
              return FlatButton(
                  onPressed: onPressed,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .primaryTextTheme
                        .button
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
              stream: device.state,
              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                leading: (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected)
                    ? Icon(Icons.bluetooth_connected)
                    : Icon(Icons.bluetooth_disabled),
                title: Text(
                    'Device is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]}.'),
                subtitle: Text('${device.id}'),
                trailing: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                  stream: device.isDiscoveringServices,
                  initialData: false,
                  builder: (c, snapshot) => IndexedStack(
                    index: snapshot.data ? 1 : 0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        onPressed: () => device.discoverServices(),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          width: 18.0,
                          height: 18.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: device.mtu,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                title: Text('MTU Size'),
                subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () => device.requestMtu(223),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
              stream: device.services,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: _buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the **widgets.dart**:

```
// Copyright 2017, Paul DeMarco.
// All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class ScanResultTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScanResultTile({Key key, this.result, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  final ScanResult result;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  Widget _buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    if (result.device.name.length > 0) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            result.device.name,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          Text(
            result.device.id.toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
          )
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Text(result.device.id.toString());
    }
  }

  Widget _buildAdvRow(BuildContext context, String title, String value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 4.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
          SizedBox(
            width: 12.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              value,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .caption
                  .apply(color: Colors.black),
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String getNiceHexArray(List<int> bytes) {
    return '[${bytes.map((i) => i.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(', ')}]'
        .toUpperCase();
  }

  String getNiceManufacturerData(Map<int, List<int>> data) {
    if (data.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }
    List<String> res = [];
    data.forEach((id, bytes) {
      res.add(
          '${id.toRadixString(16).toUpperCase()}: ${getNiceHexArray(bytes)}');
    });
    return res.join(', ');
  }

  String getNiceServiceData(Map<String, List<int>> data) {
    if (data.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }
    List<String> res = [];
    data.forEach((id, bytes) {
      res.add('${id.toUpperCase()}: ${getNiceHexArray(bytes)}');
    });
    return res.join(', ');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: _buildTitle(context),
      leading: Text(result.rssi.toString()),
      trailing: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('CONNECT'),
        color: Colors.black,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: (result.advertisementData.connectable) ? onTap : null,
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildAdvRow(
            context, 'Complete Local Name', result.advertisementData.localName),
        _buildAdvRow(context, 'Tx Power Level',
            '${result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel ?? 'N/A'}'),
        _buildAdvRow(
            context,
            'Manufacturer Data',
            getNiceManufacturerData(
                    result.advertisementData.manufacturerData) ??
                'N/A'),
        _buildAdvRow(
            context,
            'Service UUIDs',
            (result.advertisementData.serviceUuids.isNotEmpty)
                ? result.advertisementData.serviceUuids.join(', ').toUpperCase()
                : 'N/A'),
        _buildAdvRow(context, 'Service Data',
            getNiceServiceData(result.advertisementData.serviceData) ?? 'N/A'),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ServiceTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothService service;
  final List<CharacteristicTile> characteristicTiles;

  const ServiceTile({Key key, this.service, this.characteristicTiles})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (characteristicTiles.length > 0) {
      return ExpansionTile(
        title: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Service'),
            Text('0x${service.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .body1
                    .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color))
          ],
        ),
        children: characteristicTiles,
      );
    } else {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text('Service'),
        subtitle:
            Text('0x${service.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}'),
      );
    }
  }
}

class CharacteristicTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic;
  final List<DescriptorTile> descriptorTiles;
  final VoidCallback onReadPressed;
  final VoidCallback onWritePressed;
  final VoidCallback onNotificationPressed;

  const CharacteristicTile(
      {Key key,
      this.characteristic,
      this.descriptorTiles,
      this.onReadPressed,
      this.onWritePressed,
      this.onNotificationPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
      stream: characteristic.value,
      initialData: characteristic.lastValue,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final value = snapshot.data;
        return ExpansionTile(
          title: ListTile(
            title: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Characteristic'),
                Text(
                    '0x${characteristic.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color))
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Text(value.toString()),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
          trailing: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.file_download,
                  color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
                onPressed: onReadPressed,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.file_upload,
                    color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5)),
                onPressed: onWritePressed,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                    characteristic.isNotifying
                        ? Icons.sync_disabled
                        : Icons.sync,
                    color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5)),
                onPressed: onNotificationPressed,
              )
            ],
          ),
          children: descriptorTiles,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class DescriptorTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothDescriptor descriptor;
  final VoidCallback onReadPressed;
  final VoidCallback onWritePressed;

  const DescriptorTile(
      {Key key, this.descriptor, this.onReadPressed, this.onWritePressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Descriptor'),
          Text('0x${descriptor.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .body1
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color))
        ],
      ),
      subtitle: StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
        stream: descriptor.value,
        initialData: descriptor.lastValue,
        builder: (c, snapshot) => Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
      ),
      trailing: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.file_download,
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
            onPressed: onReadPressed,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.file_upload,
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
            onPressed: onWritePressed,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AdapterStateTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const AdapterStateTile({Key key, @required this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Bluetooth adapter is ${state.toString().substring(15)}',
          style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.subhead,
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.subhead.color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```